# Error in setting Prometheus datasource in Grafana on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, traefik

I am setting up Grafana on Kubernetes with some custom dashboards and Prometheus as a default data source.

All services are running behind Traefik. Prometheus is running at https://myapp.dev/svc/prometheus/ and Grafana is running at https://myapp.dev/svc/grafana/

I can log in to both grafana(also able to see dashboards that were added to config) and prometheus, however when I test the Prometheus data source, I see the following error in grafana logs:

[image: img1]

```sh
lvl=eror msg="Data proxy error" logger=data-proxy-log userId=1 orgId=1 uname=xxx path=/api/datasources/proxy/1/api/v1/query remote_addr=192.168.64.1 referer=https://myapp.dev/svc/grafana/datasources/edit/1/ error="http: proxy error: dial tcp: lookup prometheus on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host"
```

**Grafana deployment**

```yaml
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: grafana-deployment
  labels:
    app: grafana
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: grafana
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: grafana
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: grafana
        image: grafana/grafana:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/
            name: datasource-volume
          - mountPath: /etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/
            name: dashboard-volume
          - mountPath: /var/lib/grafana
            name: grafana-storage
      volumes:
        - name: grafana-storage
          emptyDir: {}
        - configMap:
            defaultMode: 420
            name: grafana-datasource-cm
          name: datasource-volume
        - configMap:
            defaultMode: 420
            name: grafana-dashboard-cm
          name: dashboard-volume
```

**Configmap**

```yaml
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: grafana-datasource-cm
data:
  datasource.yml: |-
    apiVersion: 1
    datasources:
    - name: Prometheus
      type: prometheus
      orgId: 1
      access: proxy
      url: http://prometheus:9090/svc/prometheus/
      basicAuth: false
```

I am not sure on how to fix this error and test Prometheus datasource.

Comment: Could you please add your pometheus deployment and svc yaml?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like it cannot find the `prometheus` service in the cluster. Maybe:

- It's in a different namespace❓
- It's defined but with a different name❓

If it's a different namespace you can try changing your config with the full FQDN of the service. `prometheus.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local`

```yaml
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: grafana-datasource-cm
data:
  datasource.yml: |-
    apiVersion: 1
    datasources:
    - name: Prometheus
      type: prometheus
      orgId: 1
      access: proxy
      url: http://prometheus.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:9090/svc/prometheus/
      basicAuth: false
```

See if you can get to the service from your grafana pod :

```sh
$ kubectl exec -it <grafana-pod> sh
# curl http://prometheus.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:9090
```

✌️☮️

Comment: You are right about name, I wasn't pointing to the correct prometheus service. Please have a look at the update, it is ```prometheus-service``` and not ```prometheus```. However I still can't get through. Inside grafana container, the curl timeouts!

Comment: The configs look correct? Do you have any network policies configured?

Answer (score 3):

**Did you test the connection to the Prometheus data source after adding it?**

Notice that if you're choosing the `direct` access type and you're adding a `/` to  the end of the url - you're receiving `Unknown error`:

[image]

After removing the `/` at the end - the test should succeed:

[image]

(*) I'm on: **Grafana v3.1.1 (commit: a4d2708)**.